# How do I access data from my personal computer on my AMI instance running RStudio server

Tags: r, upload, amazon-ec2, data-access, amazon-ami

I have recently set up RStudio on an AMI ec2 instance using the process generously laid out by Louis Aslet from his [website](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/). But in an embarrassing turn of events I can't access the data I need because it resides on my personal computer.  I am new to cloud computing and have 0 functional knowledge of Linux, but I do know SQL, and R well.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is dialog in the comments about dropbox.com

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the "Upload" button in the "Files" window of Rstudio?

Answer (score 1):

use `scp`  in terminal.

#### To put files from your remote server

Example: if the files are located  locally in `~/mylocalfolder` and you want to put them in `/home/rstudio/mydata` you would execute in terminal:

```
 scp ~/mylocalfolder/*.csv ubuntu@<your address>:/home/rstudio/myData/
```

Note that if you want to access them under a different user, eg, rstudio, you need to change owners on the files.  Use `chown`

#### To grab data from your remote server

Example: if the files are located on `/home/rstudio/mydata` and you want to put them locally in `~/mylocalfolder` you would use

```
 scp ubuntu@<your address>:/home/rstudio/myData*.Rda ~/mylocalfolder
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the RStudio AMI all the time and what works for me is to use Dropbox. I can't remember exactly how I did it but I think I may have started the shell from within RStudio and installed Dropbox from the command line.

This link has a little more info:

http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/#comment-1041983219